# jest.mock(..) not working in 'describe' (TypeError: moduleName.split is not a function)

Tags: jestjs, jest-fetch-mock

**jest.mock(..)** does not seem to work at the '**describe**' level for my tests.

If I have the following :

```
import React from 'react';
import {someFunction} from "./something/someFile";

describe('Overview Test', () => {

    jest.mock(someFunction);

    test(' snapshot', () => {

    });
});
```

Then running the 'test' (ie. at the test level), works fine.

But if I run the 'describe' (ie. the describe level or suite level), then I get the following error :

```
TypeError: moduleName.split is not a function

    at Resolver.resolveModuleFromDirIfExists (A:\frontend\node_modules\jest-resolve\build\index.js:224:30)
    at Resolver.resolveModule (A:\frontend\node_modules\jest-resolve\build\index.js:252:12)
```

If I have this :

```
describe('Overview Test', () => {
    test(' snapshot', () => {
        jest.mock(someFunction);
    });
});
```

Then both ways it does not work.

I have also tried this :

```
import React from 'react';
import {someFunction} from "./something/someFile";


describe('Overview Test', () => {

    beforeEach(() => {
        jest.mock(someFunction);
    });

    test(' snapshot', () => {

    });
});
```

And it does not work.

**UPDATE**

I have also tried this and it does not work :

```
import React from 'react';
import {someFunction} from "./something/someFile";

    describe('Overview Test', () => {

        jest.mock('./something/someFile', () => {
            return { someFunction: jest.fn(() => "futhissit")};
        });

        test(' snapshot', () => {
            someFunction()
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Jest [`mock`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options) is for mocking modules and the first argument is the `moduleName` which it has to be a valid module name (*inside `node_modules` or a file path*) and not a direct function/module:

> #### [`jest.mock(moduleName, factory, options)`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options)
>
> Mocks a module with an auto-mocked version when it is being required. `factory` and `options` are optional.

The error you're getting `TypeError: moduleName.split is not a function` is because [`resolveModuleFromDirIfExists`](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/packages/jest-resolve/src/index.ts#L137) tries to split the module name/path and you can see it inside [`jest-resolve/src/index.ts`](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/packages/jest-resolve/src/index.ts#L207) at line `207`.

When you want to test an ES module, you pass the module location for the `moduleName` and you create a `factory` using `__esModule: true` and then create properties with exported functions being mocked using `jest.fn()`:

#### `someFile.js` exports the `someFunction`:

```js
module.exports.someFunction = () => 'Some function result!';
```

#### Mocking `someFile.js` module using [`jest.mock()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options)

```js
describe('Overview Test', () => {

  // Mock the module and its functions
  jest.mock('./someFile', () => ({
    __esModule: true,
    someFunction: jest.fn(() => 'Mocked someFunction!')
  }));

  // Import the function from the mocked module
  const { someFunction } = require('./someFile');

  test('snapshot', () => {
    // Execute the mocked function
    const someResult = someFunction();

    // Expect to return the mocked value
    expect(someResult).toBe('Mocked someFunction!');
  });

});
```

You have to import the mocked modules after the `jest.mock` module mocking. You can create a `jest.setup.js` and configure it using [`setupFilesAfterEnv`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#setupfilesafterenv-array) that can have your mocks inside it and then just import the modules like normal at the top of the test files.

Comment: thanks, i got muddled up with exporting of modules.. happy lockdown!

Comment: mocking the module before it gets imported directly or as a nested dependency was the trick. Gracias!!!

Comment: For me, my tests stopped working after upgrading to jest v27 and were all giving an error about my jest.mock hooks reference (in my setupFileAfterEnv file) not being a function.  Adding the `__esModule: true` did the trick for me, so thank you!

Comment: You shouldn't need to mock the module before import explicitly as jest performs "hoisting", no?