# jest.mock() doesn't work inside tests, only outside tests

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have a simple suite of tests where in some cases I want to mock a module and in some cases not. However, `jest.mock()` works only if it's placed outside tests. Anyone has an idea why is that and what I'm doing wrong?

This is the actual import of a function I want to mock

```
import {hasSupport, getCallingCode} from 'utils/countryCallingCode';
```

And this is the mock of this function:

```
jest.mock('utils/countryCallingCode', () => ({
    getCallingCode: () => '1',
    hasSupport: () => true,
  }));
```

Now, the working scenario is:

```
//imports
//mock

describe('...', () -> {
    it('...', () -> {

    });
});
```

This DOESN'T work:

```
//imports

describe('...', () -> {
    //mock

    it('...', () -> {

    });
});
```

This also DOESN'T work:

```
//imports

describe('...', () -> {
    it('...', () -> {
        //mock
    });
});
```

Comment: Another alternative would be to try using `jest.spyOn` in different test suites

Comment: This is exactly my issue. Any update on this question?

Comment: @javaPlease42 Yeah I don't remember finding a straight solution for this.. you'd have to find a workaround here :)

Comment: I might start a bouty for this :) My workaround for to have a seperate test file for each flow I want to mock. Not ideal but I can at least test everything. @k-wasilewski

Comment: Does `jest.doMock()` work for you?

Comment: it's the same case

Answer (score 9):

## Use `mockReturnValue(...)`

```
import {
  getCallingCode,
  hasSupport,
} from 'utils/countryCallingCode'

jest.mock('utils/countryCallingCode', () => ({
  getCallingCode: jest.fn(),
  hasSupport: jest.fn(),
}))

describe('...', () => {
    it('...', () => {
        getCallingCode.mockReturnValue(1)
        hasSupport.mockReturnValue(false)

        expect(...
    })

    it('...', () => {
        getCallingCode.mockReturnValue(0)
        hasSupport.mockReturnValue(true)

        expect(...
    })
})
```

#### Dealing with default export from that util:

```
import theUtil from 'utils/theUtil'

jest.mock('utils/theUtil', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  default: jest.fn(),
}))

describe('...', () => {
    it('...', () => {
        theUtil.mockReturnValue('some value')

        expect(...
    })

    it('...', () => {
        theUtil.mockReturnValue('some other value')

        expect(...
    })
})
```

#### Typescript:

Use `as jest.Mock`. eg:

```
...
(getCallingCode as jest.Mock).mockReturnValue(1)
...
(theUtil as jest.Mock).mockReturnValue('some value')
...
```

or, more cleanly:

```
import theUtil from 'utils/theUtil'

jest.mock('utils/theUtil', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  default: jest.fn(),
}))
const mockTheUtil = theUtil as jest.Mock

describe('...', () => {
    it('...', () => {
        mockTheUtil.mockReturnValue('some value')

        expect(...
    })
})
```

Comment: @Alex I doesnt work for me, Im getting "Property 'mockReturnValue' does not exist on type" when im calling "theUtil" follow your example.

Comment: @ccordon I have added a Typescript example to my answer, thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 7):

Jest automatically hoists `jest.mock` calls in ES modules to the top of the file, before any import statements. This is done in order to allow the use of the mocked module by other modules in the tree.

The [Jest documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks#using-with-es-module-imports) also provides an example repository to explain [how Jest mocking works](https://github.com/kentcdodds/how-jest-mocking-works).

If you want to prevent this automatic behaviour, you can use [jest.dontMock](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestdontmockmodulename).

Comment: Doesn't work for me, I've tried it...

Comment: You probably need to set up a reproducible sandbox example if the documentation is not doing what it says it should be doing for you.

Comment: Your link: "Caution: jest.mock calls cannot be hoisted to the top of the module if you enabled ECMAScript modules support. The ESM module loader always evaluates the static imports before executing code..." - Opposite of what you wrote but - it's probably because they added this caution after your answer

Comment: Marked down as this answer doesn't give a working example on how to mock inside describe or test functions. It's also not clear if it's possible or not, so not helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I've found using jest.spyOn inside the "it" block is a workaround that solves this issue and helpful when one wants to have different mocks per test.

Comment: Just does not work when you wanna `mock`.`spyOn` a named export :sad_face:, [read more here](https://www.chakshunyu.com/blog/how-to-mock-only-one-function-from-a-module-in-jest/)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me: [How to change the behaviour of a mocked import?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45006254/how-to-change-the-behaviour-of-a-mocked-import)

Mocking modules (might be also useful): [jest.mock(..) not working in 'describe' (TypeError: moduleName.split is not a function)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61252458/jest-mock-not-working-in-describe-typeerror-modulename-split-is-not-a-fu)

Comment: Thanks for posting this man! Works flawlessly. I saw that pattern once and didn't try it yet. But it's definitely the best one.