# Jest - How to mock a ES6 default export and then Change the default implementation/return value

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking, react-testing-library

**Background**

So I am trying to test a React functional component that calls a custom hook and depending on the return value of the hook, the component will render something differently. See below for an example:

```
// App.js

import "./styles.css";
import useCustomHook from "./useHook";

export default function App() {
  const [state, handler] = useCustomHook();

  return state ? <div>state is true</div> : <div>state is false</div>;
}

// useHook.js
import { useState } from "react";

const useCustomHook = () => {
  const [myState, setMyState] = useState(false);

  const handleSetMyState = () => {
    return setMyState((prevState) => !prevState);
  };

  return [myState, handleSetMyState];
};

export default useCustomHook;
```

and finally, my test:

```
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
import { render, screen, cleanup } from "@testing-library/react";
import App from "./App";

import useCustomHook from './useHook'; 

jest.mock("./useHook", () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  default: () => [false, jest.fn()]
}));

describe("testing App state", () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
    cleanup();
  });

  it("should render false when state is false", () => {
    // initialized as false AND mocked returned as false
    render(<App />);
    expect(screen.queryByText(/false/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
  it("should render true when state is true", () => {
    // the following doesn't work
    useCustomHook.mockImplementation(() => [ true, jest.fn() ]) // outputs error: TypeError: _useCustomHook.default.mockImplementation is not a function

    render(<App />);
    expect(screen.queryByText(/true/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

Now the test would pass in my local environment ( unfortunately codesandbox's environment has issues with jest.mock, so I cannot provide a live sample ) *but for the next test case, if the state returned is true the component should render text with "true" in it.*

**Issue**

However, I am unable to change the mocked implementation or the returned value of the mock for it to return something like `[true, jest.fn()]`

So I have been stuck on this issue for some time now and cannot find any relatable resource online that fits as a solution. I have tried the following and none worked.

- importing the custom hook in test and changing its mocked implementation ( like shown in example )
- same as above but changing its mockReturnValueOnce to `[ true, jest.fn() ]`
- adding a `__mocks__` directory in the same lvl as the hook and having a file with the same name `__mocks__/useHook.js`, and mock the whole module by `jest.mock('./useHook')` instead. Similar to this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52279609/7347545).
- (updated, also tried this as latest attempt to mock) `jest.mock('./useHook', () => ({ __esModule: true, default: {useCustomHook: jest.fn()}}))` and it still outputs the same error when I tried to change the implementation `TypeError: _useCustomHook.default.mockImplementation is not a function`

Please help, something as simple as changing a mocked returned value is done so easily with other languages and testing frameworks.  Why is jest complaining about?

Answer (score 2):

The default export is not a mock function, you should use `jest.fn()` to create a mock function with a mock implementation.

```
jest.mock('./useHook', () => ({
  __esModule: true,

  // It should be
  default: jest.fn(() => [false, jest.fn()]),

  // NOT
  // default: () => [false, jest.fn()]
}));
```

But test implementation details are not encouraged. See [What you should avoid with Testing Library](https://testing-library.com/docs/#what-you-should-avoid-with-testing-library)

> Testing Library encourages you to avoid testing implementation details like the internals of a component you're testing (though it's still possible). The Guiding Principles of this library emphasize a focus on tests that closely resemble how your web pages are interacted by the users.

> You may want to avoid the following implementation details:

> 1. Internal state of a component
> 2. Internal methods of a component
> 3. Lifecycle methods of a component
> 4. Child components

Comment: Im sorry, it seemed like the logic solution. But when I tried it, I received: `TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))`

Comment: and you are absolutely right about the implementation details, but this seemed like such a trivial thing that I've been stuck on, and I just want to find a viable solution if I were ever to be in that issue again

Comment: So I kept trying and the only way I was able to get your solution to initially work was using `..., default: ()=>jest.fn(()=>[false, jest.fn()])()`, then after changing the export's implementation it resulted in the same error. I will keep trying diff things to see and update the post, thank you

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find a workaround instead.

```
// test.js
import * as useCustomHook from './useHook';

// then inside my individual test

it('should render true when state is true"', () => {
  const mockHook = jest.spyOn(useCustomHook, 'default');
  mockHook.mockImplementation(() => [true, jest.fn()]);
  render(<App />);
  expect(screen.queryByText(/true/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Not sure why `jest.mock` doesn't work, but I was able to make it work with `jest.spyOn`. If anyone is able to shed some light on why one method worked and the other didn't, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I just ran into the issue of `jest.mock` not working for me. Turns out you need to run it outside your describe blocks: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70566676/jest-mock-doesnt-work-inside-tests-only-outside-tests